# What's the meaning of "discrete" in the next theorem?

Tags: calculus, analysis, ultrametric

I have a quiestion. I don't understand the meaning of "discrete" in the next theorem. I don't get why the author deduces that the set in the antepenultimate line is finite. The book is "Non-Archimedean Analysis" by S. Bosch, U. Güntzer and R. Remmert. The proposition is in page 15. Thank you for your help.

[image]

Comment: Presumably, for $A\subseteq G$, the author indicates with $\lvert A\rvert$ the image set of $A$ via the norm function.

Comment: Every point has a neighborhood free of other points of the set.

Comment: Yes, $|A|=\{|a|\,:\, a\in A\}$.

Comment: I thinking in a set with this definition of discrete, but the set in antepenultimate line wouldn't be finite. For example, $\{1/n\,:\, n\in \mathbb{N}\}$ or any translation and / or dilatation of this set.

Comment: @JuanCaldera you are missing the hypothesis that $H$ is a subgroup of $G$ and not a simple subset.

Answer (score 1):

Usually, in this context, discrete means that the subspace topology of $|H-\{0\}|$ as a subspace of $(0,\infty)$ equipped with the order topology is the discrete topology. In other words, a subset $A$ of $(0,\infty)$ is discrete if $A$ can be covered by disjoint open intervals each of them containing only one element of $A$.

Every subgroup of $((0,\infty),\cdot)$ is either dense or discrete. And if it is discrete and non-trivial, then it is cyclic, i.e. of the form $\{s^n:n\in\mathbb{Z}\}$ for some $s\neq1$, $s>0$. A proof of this fact can be found in B.5.2 of *Niel Shell, Topological fields and near valuations, Monographs and textbooks in pure and applied mathematics, vol. 135, Dekker, 1990.*

In your posted Proposition 4, we can assume that $|H-\{0\}|=\{s^n:n\in\mathbb{Z}\}$ for some $s\neq1$, $s>0$.

Therefore, if $\alpha>0$ then  $|H-\{0\}|\cap [\alpha,\alpha+1)$ is finite. Then every subset of it will be finite as well, indeed, $\{|a+h|: h\in H \mbox{ and }|aH|\leq|a+h|<|aH|+1 \}$ is finite because it is a subset of $$|H-\{0\}|\cap [|aH|,|aH|+1).$$